# R - Mutate column based on another column

Tags: r, dataframe, calculated-columns, dplyr

Using R:
For the dataframe:

```
A<-c(3,3,3,3,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
df<-data.frame(A)
```

How do you add a column such that the output is the same as:

```
A<-c(3,3,3,3,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
df<-data.frame(A)

B<-c(1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0)
mutate(df,B)
```

In other words, is there a formula for column 'B' - such that it looks at column 'A'....and lists '1', 3 times the puts a '0' .....etc etc.

So - the desired output (given column 'A') is:

[image]

Thankyou.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean. Do you want to add the vector B to the data.frame df?

Comment: I've edited the question with the desired output - thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I assign a new group each time `A` changes, then within each group put a 1 in `B` in the first #A rows.

(If the values of `A` are distinct for each group, you could replace the first two lines with `group_by(A)`, but unclear if that's a fair assumption.)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(group = cumsum(A != lag(A, default = 0))) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(B = 1 * (row_number() <= A)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

result

```
# A tibble: 11 x 3
       A group     B
   <dbl> <int> <dbl>
 1     3     1     1
 2     3     1     1
 3     3     1     1
 4     3     1     0
 5     1     2     1
 6     1     2     0
 7     2     3     1
 8     2     3     1
 9     2     3     0
10     2     3     0
11     2     3     0
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am after - that's great - thankyou very much.

Answer (score 0):

After grouping by 'A', use `rep` with 1, 0 on the value of 'A' and the difference of number of rows with group value

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df %>%
   group_by(A, grp = rleid(A)) %>%
   mutate(B =  rep(c(1, 0), c(first(A), n() - first(A)))) %>%   
   ungroup  %>%
   select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 11 x 2
#       A     B
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     3     1
# 2     3     1
# 3     3     1
# 4     3     0
# 5     1     1
# 6     1     0
# 7     2     1
# 8     2     1
# 9     2     0
#10     2     0
#11     2     0
```

---

Or using `rle` from `base R`

```
with(rle(df$A), rep(rep(c(1, 0), length(values)),  c(values, lengths-values)))
#[1] 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0
```